# Improving Big-O Value When Flattening Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, big-o

I have created an object that helps me flatten an object with nested objects.  For example, imagine that I have the following object:

```
const sampleObj = {
  outside: "string text goes here...",
  inside: {
    home: "string text goes here...",
    car:  "string text goes here...",
    shed: "string text goes here..."
  },
};
```

Now, what I want to do is return a new object that looks like this:

```
const newObj = {
  outside: "string text goes here...",
  inside: "string text goes here... string text goes here... string text goes here..."

};
```

To do so, I have created the following function:

```
function flattenObj(obj) {
  let result = {};
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (typeof val === "string") {
      result[key] = val;
    } else {
      result[key] = Object.values(val).join(" ");
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now, this works -- it does exactly what I want it to do.  However, it's Big-O value is O(n^2) -- since I am using `Object.values()` within `Object.entries()`.

I am wondering, is there a way to rewrite this algorithm so that it will be more efficient?  My sense is that we can get it to O(n), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Codesandbox example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-currying-btz4i?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Your code cannot possibly do what the first part of your question describes.

Comment: No, your code is not `O(n²)`. It's `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the size of the outer objects and `m` is the size of the inner objects. This is normal when working with all values of nested structures, and cannot be improved.

Comment: Could you edit your question and make your code a runnable snippet, working on sample data and outputting the result? This will clarify the contradictions that currently exist in your question.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, when I wrote the question I created a sample of what I am trying to accomplish.  When doing so, I did not properly write the result I was looking for.  I have now updated the question with the proper result.

Comment: @Bergi I am new to algorithms and the issue of Big-O.  I just finished a course on it, but in that course they did not discuss O(n*m).  I am wondering, though, what is the difference.  Theoretically n and m can be the same size -- in which case it would be n^2.

Comment: @trincot I rewrote it and added a link to a codesandbox example.

Comment: That is not what I meant: essential information should not be behind a link. You can use the toolbar button to create a runnable snippet inside your question.

Comment: @Moshe Sure they could be of the same size. But that doesn't change that `O(n²)` is the best you can achieve if `n` measures the number of properties in one object. It's similar to painting a wall: you need `O(a)` buckets of paint for a wall of area `a`. Or `O(w*h)` buckets of paint for a rectangular wall of width `w` and height `h`. Or `O(s²)` buckets of paint for a quadratic wall of side length `s`.

Comment: The Big-O of an algorithm *always* depends on what property of the input you are measuring. Often that's just some generic "average size `n`" with lots of assumptions, but you need a precise idea of what the variable(s) mean to arrive at a correct result. This might be the most important lesson when learning about algorithmic complexity. A course that did not discuss this is not worth its salt :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks -- very helpful and much appreciated.